# Remove line breaks POSTed as a result from pasting XML body into Fiddler

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I created some XML in notepad (figuring any extra characters or formatting would be stripped = plain string) and then pasted it into Fiddler. It looks like this:

```
<MyValue1>AB</MyValue1>
<MyValue2>BlahBlah</MyValue2>
```

When I inspect the raw message in my Web API service I see notation like the following:

```
<MyValue1>AB</MyValue1>\r\n\t\t<MyValue2>BlahBlah</MyValue2>\r\n\t\t
```

Notice the `\r\n\t\t`?

If I go back to Fiddler and make the XML into a *single line string* as opposed to a formatted and indented XML document, then I do not see those characters.

1. How do I make it so those line breaks are not a part of the XML being POSTed to my service without having to make a single line of XML in Fiddler?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. I think you're asking: "How do I tell Fiddler to send one thing and have it actually send another?" Which begs the question: "Why would you consider this behavior desirable?"

Comment: @EricLaw - Absolutely you may be and probably are (because you created it) correct. If I am misunderstanding what is supposed to be happening, write that as the answer to explain it to me. If pressing 'return' to a new line adds in Fiddler or Notepad adds `\r\n\t\t` and it is supposed to be that way then just hep me understand. I have worked with formatted XML for years and not seen this output Between XML nodes on new lines. Maybe I am just not understanding what's occurring exactly.

Comment: In text, the sequence \r\n is a linefeed and \t is a tab. When you convert a block of text into a string, these forms of whitespace are converted into the control character sequences described. If you wish to omit the control characters, you must remove the whitespace before constructing the string.

Comment: @EricLaw - That's the explanation I needed and is actually the answer. Can you please move (copy/paste) this into the answer so I can mark it as so? Does Fiddler have any documentation you can link to explaining this known behavior?